# Unchecking "Run WWW service in IIS 5.0 isolation mode" is not persisted in IIS 6

Tags: iis-6

I'm trying to switch an IIS configuration over to using application pools instead of application protection.

When I right-click the "Web Sites" node and go into Properties, then Service tab, I uncheck the "Run WWW service in IIS 5.0 isolation mode" setting. Clicking Apply, I'm prompted to restart IIS. After restarting, if I go through the same steps, the checkbox is still there.  It does switch to listing application pools (until the next time I re-open the IIS Manager) but it shows "Application Protection" instead of "Application Pool" when trying to configure a site or virtual directory.

Why isn't IIS storing my setting to not use IIS 5 isolation?

Comment: I actually have the exact opposite problem... [here is my question](http://serverfault.com/questions/449093/setting-run-www-service-in-iis-5-0-isolation-mode-does-not-persist-in-iis-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting change you made is not persisted because the IIS metabase file on disk has not been updated before the IIS restart occurs.  The change is only retained in the in-memory IIS metabase cache at first.  A forceful restart of IIS will result in losing your change.

I have answered my ["opposite problem" question](https://serverfault.com/questions/449093/setting-run-www-service-in-iis-5-0-isolation-mode-does-not-persist-in-iis-6?lq=1) on ServerFault with the solution to this root cause.

Also, see here for [Microsoft KB 286196](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286196) which outlines a workaround.